# system.out.println(tresset object)

Tags: java, treeset, system.out

i was wondering what whill this code do? It prints all couple  of the TreeSet?
Its really possible to print out the TreeSet just with a System.out.println?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TreeSet <Moulage> treeSetMoulages = new TreeSet <Moulage> ();
Moulage moulage = new Moulage ("REF24", "Cervidé","Bronze");
treeSetMoulages.add(moulage);
moulage = new Moulage ("REF44", "Insigne de chefferie","Bois");
treeSetMoulages.add(moulage);
moulage = new Moulage ("REF63", "Panthere","Marbre");
treeSetMoulages.add(moulage);
moulage = new Moulage ("REF58", "Ours blanc","Marbre");
treeSetMoulages.add(moulage);
moulage = new Moulage ("REF78", "Danseuse","Bronze");
treeSetMoulages.add(moulage);
System.out.println (treeSetMoulages);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will print it out like an array as long as a Moulage is a printable class.

Comment: how do i know if it's a printable class?

Comment: @youngknight if you have implemented the `toString` method. System.out.println(object) calls the `toString` method on the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it depends on the `Moulage` class and its `toString()` implementation. `Moulage` class also has to implement `Comparable`. If these two conditions are satisfied the `System.out.println` will print the elements.

Comment: oh thank you,i understand now, and compareTo() will say to the TreeSet how it must be sort out? (sorry for my bad english,dont know if its understandable)

Comment: Right, the `compareTo()` method decides how to compare and sort the set.